# How to separate charaters from char pointer in C

Tags: c, loops, char

I have `pipeline` variable in my `C` file:

```
const char *pipeline = "1|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90";

static int doWork(char *data, char *res_data) {

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++) {
    int index = // here I want to get 1,12,23... as integer to be used as index for my purpose
  }
}
```

My question is that, how can I read `1,12,23,...,n` from `char *` ?

**Edit:**

Also, following points need to be considered:

1. Range of number can be any. There can be 10 or 84 or 55 in pipeline.
2. I want `index=1 for i=0`, `index=12 for i=1`, `index=23 for i=2` and so on.

Comment: You assign the numbers to your counter variable which hasn't been declared before use. That's a typo right?

Comment: Try strtok() http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `strtol()`? It would make this *very* simple.

Comment: Or just `continue` where `data[i] == '|'`. And you still didn't declare `i`. @EOF Is it ironic that your username is EndOfFile when you answer string related questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works if `pipeline` is allowed to be `char[]` instead of `char *`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char pipeline[] = "1|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90";
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (pipeline,"|");
    int num;
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        sscanf (pch,"%d",&num);
        printf("%d\n",num);
        pch = strtok (NULL, "|");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char *pipeline = "1|12|23|34|45|56|67|78|89|90";
    char *pch=pipeline;
    while (*pch)
    {
        int index=strtol(pch,&pch,10);
        printf("%d\n",index);
        if(*pch=='|')
            pch++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I may change to array from pointer. can this be useful for point (2) in my edit?

Comment: @astuter You can just int i=0; and then i++ in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

Given your `pipeline` format, I guess this is what you need:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++) {
    int j;
    if( ( i % 2 ) == 0 )
    {
        j = *(data + i) - '0';  // j = 1,2,3 and so on..
    }
}
```